# About HTML5 Canvas transform matrix

Tags: html, canvas, transform

In a lot of Html5 related books, authors often mentioned:

`transform(1,0,0,1,0,0)` equals `transform(0,1,1,0,0,0)`.

I'm puzzled about this. In my opinion, that means

`newX = oldX/newY = oldY` equals `newX = oldY/newY = oldX`.

That means swap the x and y!!!!

Am I wrong? Who can explain it to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that's completely wrong.  In the first you're getting an identity matrix:

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

and with the 2nd you get

```
0 1 0
1 0 0
0 0 1
```

Saying they're identical is BS.